Я установила CUDA, но Python на PyCharm Community Edition его не видит
Установила cuda_11.2.0_460.89_win10.exe и cudnn_8.1.0_windows.exe.
Установилась CUDA в C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit
Поставила самый последний драйвер: GeForce Game Ready - Версия: 560.94
Пути к переменные среды:
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\libnvvp
В командной строке команда: nvcc --version выдаёт:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_Pacific_Standard_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0

В PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.3 в терминале по pip list - tensorflow 2.17.0
Но в ответ на программу:
import tensorflow as tf

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

пишет:

Num GPUs Available:  0

Почему? Что я сделала не так?

Попробуйте выполнить свою программу в IDLE, попробуйте выполнить её как .py. Более идей нет. Как конкретно это должно работать и какие у него требования надо читать в документации.

Ну что ж... Спасибо!

Я Вам скажу также, что эта Cuda настолько капризна, что даже тогда, когда она должна работать, она легко может выключиться. Карта ей не понравится или ОС и всё. Не смотря ни на что. Левая технология, сильно модных видеокарт хочет. Ну и опять же. Программа рассчитана только на Nvidia? А карты AMD?

Левая что, это ладно... но быстрая!!!

tensorflow 2.17.0 - слишком поздняя версия для CUDA v11.2
Ниже совместимость
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows?hl=ru#gpu
Для tensorflow 2.17.0 нужно cuDNN  8,9  CUDA - 12.3
для куда CUDA\v11.2 можно установить tensorflow  с 2.5 по 2.11
Может еще потребоваться Visual C обновить и диркс. У меня нормально подставилась только 2.5
